# point _except_handler4_common couldnot located in msvcrt.dll in Windows XP

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-xp

My project run correctly in Windows 7 & 8, but in win xp show below error
[image]
I install .Net2.0 and 3.5 and DirectX but error has been occurred yet.
project used .Net2
How can i fix this?
Thanks

Comment: Whatever you did to get a dependency on msvcrt.dll, woefully missing from the question, you did wrong.  It is a private copy of the CRT that can only be used by Windows itself.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks but how can fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried copying your msvcrt.dll from a win7 machine to your winxp machine?  Not sure that this is a great idea, overwriting system files, but it might help you narrow down the problem.  What are the references in your project?

Comment: @paqogomez msvcrt.dll is using by windows XP and can not replace it.

Comment: You havent answered the question of references.  Have you tried using [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)?

Comment: [This](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324762) may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all. problem is WMPLib.dll, and I ask question about this in [can't use WMPLib in windows XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20071921/cant-use-wmplib-in-windows-xp). Thanks fo helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following:

http://qamarsyed.blogspot.nl/2010/08/procedure-entry-point.html

Answer (score 0):

while running the project from visual studio force the platform target as 32 bit using following steps:

```
->Right click on Project
->Select Properties
->Goto Build Options
->Change  "Platform Target" from "ANY CPU" to "X86"
```

now run the Project.

Comment: When I do this at program.cs throw an exception that don't say any yhing about exception